# How can I get the size from query result and save it in variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this website that has an error handling when adding groups, which means if I have already 5 groups the website does not allow to add more. For that to happen I query the database, and with that query result I try to access the length  from it.

If that length is <4 I will allow the group to be inserted else I will not allow and only show a message. This can be seen in the code above but for some reason it always allow the insertion into the query.

```
$con = "put the con here";     
    $query2 = "SELECT * from title where iduser= {$_SESSION['iduser']}";
            $result =  mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die (mysql_error());
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            echo $num_rows; //save the size in $num_rows
        
        
          if($num_rows < 4){  //Did the condition here
          $query="INSERT INTO grouptitle(title,iduser) VALUES ('$variavel',{$_SESSION['id_utilizador']})";
          mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysql_error());
              ?>
          <script>
          alert("Grupo adedd");
          self.location="Definitions.php";
        
        <?php }else{ ?>
        
        <script>
          alert("Exceded the group limit");
          self.location="Definitions.php";
        
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: First of all, stop using `mysql_*` library. Second, why are you even mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` functions?. Third, you are not closing your `<script>` tags.

Comment: yes it solve the problem :)

Comment: Why did you put -1? It was a good question

Answer (score 0):

The 4th line of your code there buddy... try this

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```